# WPF or Silverlight, XML or SQL or Access, LINQ or not?

Tags: sql, wpf, xml, silverlight, ms-access

I am writing a Windows app and want to make sure I am choosing the right tools. Currently I am leaning towards WPF and XML, please let me know if I've made a good choice.

I have about 3,000 records. Each record has a Product Name and a Price columns.
All my app does is display these records in a DataGrid and allows the user to search for products by name. Meaning, if a user types 'chair' in an edit control, then only the Product Names that contain 'chair' and their prices are displayed in the DataGrid. That's it. Nothing fancy.

1. Should I use Silverlight instead of WPF? I understand Silverlight allows my app to run on any OS, while WPF requires Windows? Unless I create a WPF for browser project, I think.
2. Should I use XML or Access or SQL? Which database would make the SEARCH feature easiest, fastest, etc.?
3. Finally, should/does LINQ have any involvement in this project?

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends. What is the environment that your end-user will be operating in?

Comment: These questions are best answered by software architects, and might not be a good fit for the QA format on SO. If you have specific questions about implementing your features using any of the tools/features/technologies/frameworks mentioned, this is the correct place.

Comment: This really should be multiple questions. In its current form it is too broad.

Comment: I agree. This is too broad and can solicit long discussions. We can't answer a question that has embedded questions with different topic correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its going to be a stand alone product i.e. installed a each computer and not networked in any way then personally I would go for a SQLCE database with a WPF client. Its up to you if you use LINQ, I quite like it but would be overkill for this app maybe.

The next stage up is a small app used by a handful of users in a network. In this instance I would use an access backend (assuming a fileserver is in place) with a WPF client application.

Right at the “top” of the scale would be something used by a lot of people and/or something on the web. In this case I would use SQL server as the backend and again a WPF client app or if you want it to run on other platforms then go for silverlight